# 301 Redirecting

Tags: .htaccess

Is there anything I could do to improve the following `.htaccess` code?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect non-www to www.
# http://{domain}/
# http://www.{domain}/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=localhost [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=127.0.0.1
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=127.0.0.1
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=::1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect trailing slash to non-trailing slash.
# http://www.{domain}/foo/
# http://www.{domain}/foo
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect trailing ".php" to extensionless.
# http://www.{domain}/foo.php
# http://www.{domain}/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s.+\.php\sHTTP/.+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect "/index" to root.
# http://www.{domain}/index
# http://www.{domain}/
RewriteRule ^index$ / [NC,R=301,L]

# Forward to version with ".php" extension.
# http://www.{domain}/foo
# http://www.{domain}/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can compress the `www` redirection to:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(localhost|127\.0\.0\.1|www\.) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=(127\.0\.0\.1|::1)
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

When redirecting `.php` to extensionless pages, you are not considering the query strings, which can be handled as follows (unless you do not want to do so):

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s.+\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L,NC,QSA]
```

While adding `QSA` is not required, you should practice putting the flag as it might later on help you deal with infinite recursions. The same `QSA` can be added to the last rule, where you put back the `.php` extensions.

Answer (score 1):

Use of `%{THE_REQUEST}` isn't idiomatic, and I don't see any purpose for the first `RewriteCond` in

> ```
> # Redirect trailing ".php" to extensionless.
> # http://www.{domain}/foo.php
> # http://www.{domain}/foo
> RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s.+\.php\sHTTP/.+ [NC]
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
> RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
> ```

Comment: If I remove the first `RewriteCond` in there, I get an `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS` error from Chrome.

Comment: @KidDiamond You probably have `Options MultiViews` enabled. disable it.

Comment: @hjpotter92 Tried disabling it in my .htaccess. It didn't work.